# LazyVstack inside TabView

Tags: swiftui, lazy-loading, swiftui-tabview, lazyvstack

LazyVstack insde TabView wrapped on scrollView not working (performance issue)

```
var body: some View {
      ScrollView {
        Text("hello, world!")
        TabView(selection: $tab) {
          p1().tag(0)
          P2().tag(1) 
        }
      }
}
```

```
Struct P1: View {
   var body: some View {
      LazyVstack {
        Foreach(0...150, id: \.self) { i in
       Text("Row -> \(i)")
      }
   }
}
```

So all rows in LazyVsatck was rendering
From 0 to 149 once , lazy behavior not working here with TabView how i can achieve and solve this issue

Comment: Tab view should always be at the very top

Comment: @loremipsum but I have an case to do like code in above and lazy rendering not working

Comment: It isn’t optional Apple specified in the HIG that the tab bar must always be at the top. You can create your own and see if it works.

Comment: A lot of options was created, but nothing is right , did you have an example of this ?